# Image map and some cases in chrome not working

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm close to giving up.

I'm in an investigation for about 4 hours. And I can't find what is the problem of this page.

I have this page in staging http://www-s.trueaussiebeefandlamb.com/proteins/grassfed-beef/ and this in pre-production http://www-p.trueaussiebeefandlamb.com/proteins/grassfed-beef/

In staging works fine in all browsers. In Pre, in Chrome the mouse hover of the beef not change the image. The idea is when the user mouse over the animal the cut highlighted. This works fine in IE.

In my investigation, if I change the `background: url("../lamb-sprite.png");` to `background: red url("../lamb-sprite.png");` in Chrome-devtools the bahaviour works.

I don't want to add any kind of Jquery to change the CSS of this page. I don't think this is the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the image is hidden behind some value of z-index. Try:

```
.protein-cut .image-map img {
  display: block;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: That site made me hungry!

Comment: maybe it's because the image [beef | lamb]-sprite.png is not loaded by lazy load chrome that only loads [beef|lamb].png without the sprite version. You could try to add a tag with that image with `display:none`.